# node.js mongoose session issues. Undefined when defined?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, mongoose, express

im developing a small application with login and having an issue accessing session data.

nb: using express 3.0, coffee-script and mongoose

So in my app I have the following:

```
app.locals.use (req,res) ->
  res.locals.session = req.session
  res.locals.title = config.title
  res.locals.href = config.href
```

In my login.coffee I do the following:

```
ModelUser.findOne {email: email, password: password}, (err, results) ->
    if err then console.log err
    if results?
       req.session.user = results
       req.session.authenticated = true
       res.redirect '/'
    else
       req.session.error = 'bad login'
       res.redirect '/'
```

If I go to output `#{session.user}` in Jade, I get `[bject,Object]`, but if I enter in "name" or "email" it returns blank. If I go into console and log the session object in the app.coffee, you can see the following:

`if req.session? then console.log req.session.user`

returns:

```
{ _id: '4f9b60ba7a7ab7e7f711920e',
  email: 'foobar@gmail.com',
  name: 'Demo User',
  password: '078d2bf82ee269cd9577588d212655c3a2162dc5b09e7c29c6a343926ee881a9' }
```

But if do `console.log req.session.user.email` it gives me a 500 error saying its not defined.. but I dont know why because you can see it is defined.

**EDIT:**

Solved; It was an async issue with the application continuing on before it got the user.
Had to send a callback to the find and use next()

```
if req.session.authenticated 
    require('./lib/getUser')(req.session.uid, (results) ->
      res.locals.user = results
      console.log res.locals
      done()
    )
  else
    done()
```

Comment: Resolved it. Was an asynchronous issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an async issue with the application flow. The server is continuing before the results  are returned, thus being undefined.